# Form Select not adding values to Angular variable

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular17

Learning Angular 17 and having issues with form-select values binding to the nested class `ClientLocations` in class `Projects`.
My `modal` form

```xml
<div class="form-group row pt-1 pb-1">
                        <label for="txtNewClientLocations" class="col-sm-4 form-select-label pt-2">Client Locations</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <select class="form-select" [(ngModel)]="newProject.clientLocationID" name="ClientLocation" aria-label="Please Select" id="txtNewClientLocations">
                                <option default value="null">Please Select</option>
                                <option *ngFor="let clientLocation of clientLocations" [value]="clientLocation.clientLocationID">{{clientLocation.clientLocationName}}</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

My `Project` class:

```js
export class Project {
    projectID: number|null;
    projectName: string|null;
    dateOfStart: string|null;
    teamSize: number|null;
    active: boolean;
    status: string|null;
    clientLocationID: number|null;
    clientLocation: ClientLocation|null;

    constructor(){
        this.projectID = null;
        this.projectName = null;
        this.dateOfStart = null;
        this.teamSize = null;
        this.active = true;
        this.status = null;
        this.clientLocationID = null;
        this.clientLocation = new ClientLocation();
    }
}
```

```js
export class ClientLocation {
    clientLocationID: number;
    clientLocationName: string;

    constructor(){
        this.clientLocationID = -1;
        this.clientLocationName = "";
    }
}
```

For all other form elements, able to look and register the values to the backend. However, the this form-select is not able to add the values to the `ClientLocations` nested class in the `Projects` class. It just shows up as default constructor values of `newProject` variable.

Comment: there is no `ClientLocations` in the code you shared, please share more details! if possible a stackblitz!

Comment: @NarenMurali Added the class description

Comment: its still unclear, where is `ClientLocations` coming from, its not there in your component code!

Comment: @NarenMurali https://stackblitz.com/~/github.com/Ishaangt/TaskManager

Comment: please share the sample API response of `/api/clientlocations` in your backend

Comment: GET /api/clientlocations
Response:  [
  { clientLocationID: 1, clientLocationName: 'Boston' },
  { clientLocationID: 2, clientLocationName: 'London' },
  { clientLocationID: 3, clientLocationName: 'New Jersy' }
]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256695/discussion-between-grim42-and-naren-murali).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the change event to update the property `clientLocation` based on the dropdown data `clientLocations` and the selected ID in `clientLocationID`

The select is setting the value as string, but ID is generally a number, to make the find work properly you need to use `==` which does not strictly check the types and the object will get matched!

```
setClientLocation() {
    this.newProject.clientLocation = this.clientLocations.find((item: ClientLocation) => 
        item.clientLocationID == this.newProject.clientLocationID) || null;
}
```

In the HTML, on change of the dropdown, we can add `(ngModelChange)` and trigger the above function to update the property `clientLocation` based on the selection!

```
<div class="form-group row pt-1 pb-1">
    <label for="txtNewClientLocations" class="col-sm-4 form-select-label pt-2">Client Locations</label>
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <select class="form-select" [(ngModel)]="newProject.clientLocationID" name="ClientLocation" aria-label="Please Select" id="txtNewClientLocations">
                 <option default value="null">Please Select</option>
                 <option *ngFor="let clientLocation of clientLocations" [value]="clientLocation.clientLocationID">{{clientLocation.clientLocationName}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
</div>
```